# setTimeout failing after first iteration

Tags: javascript

After the first iteration , the setTimeout is failing due to variable i is undefined and as a result i am seeing pollundefined error in console

Please excuse , i am a java guy and very little knowledge on UI Side

```
var symbols = [ "ONE","TWO"];
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
  callPoll();
});

function callPoll() {
  poll(symbols[i]);
  i++;
  if (i < symbols.length)
    setTimeout(callPoll, 1500);
}

setTimeout(callPoll, 3000);

function poll(value) {
  alert('poll'+value);
}
```

Comment: Window.i = 0; make it global

Comment: instead of var i =0 ; i used window.i=0; , but still the same error .

Comment: You only call it once and the symbols array is set to the length of two. Your doing the method on a conditional bases. It will only eval to 2 on the method call. Add the timer to the jquery part and have it call the callpost function. That should call it every so often as defined by your second param.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` is not undefined, `symbols[i]` is undefined. You are starting your sequence twice, once at `setTimeout(callPoll, 3000);` and again when `$(document).ready` fires. You are setting up a call that will fire after `i` is outside the range of entries for `symbols`. Remove the first call to `setTimeout`.

```
    var symbols = [ "ONE","TWO"];
     var i = 0;
     $(document).ready(function () {
       callPoll();
     }
     );

     function callPoll() {

        poll(symbols[i]);
         i++;
         if (i < symbols.length) {
             setTimeout(callPoll, 1500);
         }
         else { 
             // reset cycle
             i = 0;
             setTimeout(callPoll, 3000);
         }
     }

     function poll(value)
     {
         alert('poll'+value);
     }
```

Comment: Thank you , but callPoll is onl getting called once .

Comment: @PreethiJain if you are getting an `undefined` error on the first alert, you must have some other code interfering that you haven't posted.

Comment: The function callPoll should get repeately called after every 3 seconds , but in your code , its being fired only once know .

Comment: Thanks , the function callPoll() should be called continously after every 3 seconds .

Comment: I mean that callPoll is responsible for taking an array and processing those (each arrray element must have  agp of 1.5 seconds) , but the callPoll should get called after every 3 secons

Comment: @PreethiJain so after you cycle through all your array items, you want to start over at the beginning? Or you just want `callPoll` to fire every 3 second no matter what?

Comment: Yes , after  cycle through all the array items, I want to start over at the beginning , I am strugling to get this work

Comment: @PreethiJain see updated code. keep in mind this is going to give you alerts forever. You might want to add a condition to skip the restart at some point.

Comment: Thank you very much sir , my sincere apologies to you all who are trying to help me . Yes i tested your edited code , its working fine . my question is itself wrong , misundersood the requirement , God bless you .

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `poll()` without checking that `i` is in range. Re-order `callPoll()` like so:

```
function callPoll() {
  if (i < symbols.length) {
    poll(symbols[i]);

    i++;
    setTimeout(callPoll, 1500);
  }
}
```

Comment: callPoll is only being called once .

Comment: The function callPoll should get repeately called after every 3 seconds , but in your code , its being fired only once know

Comment: No, in the link I included, it's called twice. Then it stops, since we've run out of symbols (rather than trying to display undefined values past the end of the symbols list).

Answer (score 0):

yes, set

```
 if (i < symbols.length-1)
             setTimeout(callPoll, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not because callback function of `setTimeout` does not "see" `i` but because it exceeds `symbols` array range.

The calls order will be:

1. callPoll from document.ready; after call `i == 1`
2. callPoll from `callPoll`'s `setTimeout`; after call `i == 2`
3. callPoll from global `setTimeout`; on enter `i == 2` so `poll` is called with `symbols[2]` which is undefined.